# What brand is this bike seat logo?

Tags: saddle

Trying to figure out what brand this bike seat is. Thank you very much for your help!![image]

Answer (score 9):

The logo says   "CODA"   which appears to be a name applied to some Cannondale components.

They have cranks and saddles branded as CODA.

[image]

Note that there's a Jamis model called a Coda - that's different again.

Comment: I would never have guessed that that said "coda", but it seems plausible now you've pointed it out.

Comment: This is correct. Cannondale's house brand is called CODA.